# React Native Input Autofill

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

I was wondering if anyone knows if 1. this is possible with react native and 2. how would I go about achieving this. It's nothing too crucial to the application but it's something nice to have. I want to display a users (ios) predetermined phone number contact information above the keyboard when focusing on the input.Here is a picture about what Im talking about shown in safari and other apps. [This first image is from Instagram which shows the user email above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiXqK.png) [This second one is from safari, which shows the phone numbers, which is want i want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8vFA.jpg)

This is the code I have for my phone number input

```
<TextInput
  keyboardType="decimal-pad"
  placeholder="Phone Number"
  placeholderTextColor="#555555"
  returnKeyType="next"
  selectionColor="#FF5349"
  textContentType="username"
/>
```

Answer (score 4):

[autoCompleteType](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#autocompletetype)

> Specifies autocomplete hints for the system, so it can provide
> autofill. On Android, the system will always attempt to offer autofill
> by using heuristics to identify the type of content. To disable
> autocomplete, set `autoCompleteType` to `off`.

```
<TextInput
  autoCompleteType="tel" // <-- suggestion for telephone autocompletion
  keyboardType="decimal-pad"
  placeholder="Phone Number"
  placeholderTextColor="#555555"
  returnKeyType="next"
  selectionColor="#FF5349"
  textContentType="username"
/>
```